# Mysql weird data in column 4294967294

Tags: mysql

This is the second time I've got 4294967294 value in this table. I have no clue where it's coming from. I checked my mysql.log and it doesn't show up anywhere there.

data type is int(3)

What's the deal?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We don't know what queries are being run, so it's anyone's guess. If it's any hint, that appears to be the max value that can be stored in an unsigned INT field.

Comment: yea, it is unsigned... what if my script is updating an unsigned int to -1 on accident? maybe this could cause this problem

Comment: That crossed my mind, but if your column is unsigned, trying to insert -1 would result in an error. Is a similar thing happening in the code before being inserted? Not sure what language you're using and whether that is likely to happen.

Comment: using php. what about an update query? i have a default value set. no where do my scripts insert a negative value.

Comment: FYI, int(3) is the same data type as int(1), int(10), or int(100).  The numbers in parentheses have the sole purpose of telling the command line mysql client how wide to make the display column when showing results of queries on that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number is 2^32 - so the largest number an unsigned int can be.  Can it be attempting to insert -1?  Is Strict SQL Mode enabled?  If not per the MySql manual:

> If no restrictive modes are enabled, MySQL clips the value to the appropriate endpoint of the range and stores the resulting value instead.

Comment: No insert is causing this because I have a default value set, maybe an update is causing this.

Comment: i removed the unsigned attribute until i find out which query is causing this. thanks!